# Send rich messages like html table in webhook response of api.ai

Tags: facebook, bots, webhooks, api-ai

I'm trying to build a bot using api.ai and connecting it with Facebook & slack integrations. My requirement is to send rich messages like HTML table, Graph snapshots like [statsbot](https://statsbot.co/) in response of the webhook in api.ai

Please anyone show me a demo of how to achieve the same.

Also, I have to make sure that there is minimal changes for the UI for slack & facebook messenger. Does API.ai handle the same automatically

Comment: Were you able to find an answer for this question?